# use scipy optimize minimize in a class

Tags: python, class, scipy-optimize-minimize

I am cleaning up some code and want to refactor code that is currently unorganized to an individual class. The code optimizes an outflow rate to match the duration outcome with the duration target and looks as follows:

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
volume = 100
value = 95
discount_rates = <some dataframe>
duration_target = 1.5
initial_guess = 0

def calculate_duration(discount_rates, outflow, volume, value)
   ...

def fun(outflow):
   duration_outcome = calculate_duration(discount_rates, outflow, volume, value)
   target = abs(duration_outcome - duration_target)
   return target

def solv():
   res = optimize.minimize(fun, initial_guess, method = 'SLSQP', tol=1e-8)
   return res.x
```

This code works, but it uses global variables that are not input for the relevant functions (initial_guess in solv(), duration_target in fun(), etc.)

I have written the following class which should accomplish the same. However, the optimization does not change the outflow parameter so the outcome does not converge.

```
import scipy.optimize as optimize
class Calculate:

    def __init__(self, discount_rates, volume, value, duration, initial_guess):


        self.discount_rates = discount_rates
        self.volume = volume
        self.value = value
        self.duration_target = duration_target
        self.initial_guess = initial_guess

    def calculate_duration(self, outflow): 
        ...

    def fun(self, outflow):
        duration_outcome = self.calculate_cashflows(outflow)

        target = abs(duration_outcome - self.duration_target)

        return target

    def solv(self):
        #  solution
        res = optimize.minimize(self.fun, self.initial_guess, method = 'SLSQP', tol=1e-8)
        return res.x
```

It is unclear for me what the problem is with my class and why the code outflow *does* converge in the first option, but *doesnt* in the second option. I.e., res.x is not the same for the two methods. What mistake did I make here?

Comment: Note that the [`minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) function can take an `args` keyword argument that is a tuple of additional parameters that the objective function requires. So, for your non-class-based method, you could define your objective function as `def fun(outflow, discount_rates, duration_target, volume, value): ...` and then use `res = optimize.minimize(fun, initial_guess, args=(discount_rates, duration_target, volume, value), ...)`.

Comment: Another nice option is to use a [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) function.

Comment: Regarding, why your class-based code doesn't correctly converge, have you checked that your `calculate_cashflows` method is doing the same as your previous `calculate_duration` function? As those are the bits of code you've not included it's hard to say for sure what the problem is.

Comment: @MattPitkin sorry, the second one should also be calculate_duration. They are the same functions

Answer (score 0):

Does the function `calculate_cashflows` change the values of `self.volume`, or any of the other variables at any point?

You say that the original code uses global variables, but that's only partly true. Inside the old function `calculate_duration`, the parameters like `volume` will be local variables. A change like `volume = volume + 10` would only affect the local variable, not the global one, so changes would be forgotten when the function ends. Meanwhile, the new function `calculate_cashflows` doesn't have a parameter for `volume`, and it presumably directly accesses `self.volume`. That means that changes can accumulate. That could explain the difference in behavior

A quick test is to try modifying `Calculate.fun` to call the original `calculate_duration` function, instead of calling `self.calculate_cashflows`. If I'm right, then that should give you the results you're looking for

Once you've identified the problem, you can probably rewrite the new function to work properly (Alternatively, you could just cut and paste the old function into the class, and label it as a `@staticmethod`)

(Btw, if the variables really are supposed to stay constant, then I think it's okay for them to be global variables. Global variables can cause problems when they actually *vary*, but global constants are different)